# Omitting visibility marker in MetaUML

Tags: symbols, metapost, metauml

Is there a way to omit the visibility (lock symbol) marker in MetaUML `Class` objects?
If I just refrain to use one I get a protected marker as a default.

A short example (*note*: the LaTeX builder has to be run with `-shell-escape` option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}[mpsettings={input metauml;},use]

Class.A("ClassA")
("-private","+public","default protected", "#protectedWithNumberSign")
();
drawObjects(A);

\end{mpost}
\end{document}
```

Just to have stated it: in section 2 *Class Diagrams* on page 6, the handbook says that `#` produces a protected marker (therefore I was tempted to think that omitting the marker symbol it would result in no marker), but in fact this produces such a marker plus a # sign.

Comment: @karlkoeller `MetaUML` is a Metapost package, which is surely on topic here.

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code.

Comment: @egreg Didn't know that, voted for reopen.

Comment: I added an example. I hope you'll find it descriptive...
Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You would have to patch `metauml_class.mp` to get it to leave out the lock symbol.  One approach would be to define a new access definition character, change `addAttribute` to accept it, and change `Class_drawFeatures` to omit the lock selectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Class_noVisibilityMarkers`.

```
Class.A("Point")
  ("#x:int", "#y:int")
  ("+toString():String");
Class_noVisibilityMarkers.A;
drawObject(A);
```

`Class_noVisibilityMarkers` was not available in MetaUML 0.2.5, but it is now available from the master branch of https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Glad to see that MetaUML is being developed again.