# Symbolic visibility markers in MetaUML

Tags: metauml

My question is very similar to this:[Omitting visibility marker in MetaUML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148817/omitting-visibility-marker-in-metauml)

Is there any way to leave `+`, `-` and `#` symbols as they are, without drawing locks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest MetaUML version from Github uses the standard accesibility symbols instead of the locks.